# Why can I not refresh my Snowflake External Table?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables

I am getting the message "query produced no results" when I try to execute a refresh of my external table in Snowflake.  Below are the steps I have taken leading up to the final statement that is not executing successfully.

When I execute the following, I can successfully see the .json file I am trying to access in my stage (azure blob storage):

```
LIST @AZURE_STAGE_ECL_RAW
```

I have created a file format as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT ECL_JSON_FORMAT
    TYPE = JSON
    FILE_EXTENSION = '.json';
```

I have ensured my .json file is of ndjson format as follows:

```
{"code": "value1", "display": "value2", "version": "value3", "cluster_name": "value4"}
{"code": "value1", "display": "value2", "version": "value3", "cluster_name": "value4"}
{"code": "value1", "display": "value2", "version": "value3", "cluster_name": "value4"}
{"code": "value1", "display": "value2", "version": "value3", "cluster_name": "value4"}
```

I created my external table as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE CLUSTERS_SNOMED_ECL
(
    Code TEXT AS (value:"code"::TEXT)
    ,Display TEXT AS (value:"display"::TEXT)
    ,Version TEXT AS (value:"version"::TEXT)
    ,Cluster_Name TEXT AS (value:"cluster_name"::TEXT)
)
WITH LOCATION = @AZURE_STAGE_ECL_RAW/clusters.json
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = ECL_JSON_FORMAT);
```

When I execute the following I can see the created columns but no data as per the attached picture:

```
SELECT * FROM CLUSTERS_SNOMED_ECL
```

[image: View when I Select * From Table]

So finally I am trying to refresh my external table for the inaugural time however when I execute the following, I am returned the message "query produced no results":

```
ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE CLUSTERS_SNOMED_ECL REFRESH;
```

Can anybody suggest what I should do next to successfully refresh and pull the data into my table?

Comment: Have you configured the right permissions to the external storage location? (like for S3 you need the [following](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-s3.html#aws-access-control-requirements). If the answer is yes you should try a direct SELECT on the external stage as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html)

Comment: Hi Sergiu, the permissions are configured corrcetly because I can see the contents of my STAGE when I use LIST@<stagename>

Comment: LIST stage is not enough, are you able to SELECT from the file of the external stage? You can use [SELECT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html) to select from files located on external stages.

Comment: I have successfully copied the data into physical tables from the external stage. But I can not refresh the external table.

Answer (score 1):

Query returned 0 results because the location is pointing directly to the file.

```html
WITH LOCATION = @AZURE_STAGE_ECL_RAW/clusters.json
```

External tables feature was designed to read all files from the directory instead of one file.

To fix this, please recreate the external table such that the location is pointing to the files directory. After that, run a select query against the external table to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can list the Metadata of the file from the stage using the command
select metadata$filename from @ZURE_STAGE_ECL_RAW;

If you get an access deny message then there is a permission issue at the file level.
ls @ZURE_STAGE_ECL_RAW, can work, if you have the permission on the Blob, but you need to have the right permission on the File as well.

Comment: Hi yes I can see the contents of the stage when I use LIST @, and I can see the metadata when I use SELECT metadata$filename from @AZURE_STAGE_ECL_RAW so I am certain I have permissions configured correctly.

Comment: I replicated the issue and I can load the file. without having permissions on the file, I too got similar behavior as yours. Once I had the permissions on the file, I am able use select on the table.   Can you open a case with Support so we can check the cnfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

The file format does not need the `FILE_EXTENSION` part:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT ECL_JSON_FORMAT
    TYPE = JSON
    -- FILE_EXTENSION = '.json';
```

[CREATE FILE FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html):

> FILE_EXTENSION = 'string' | NONE
>
> Use
>
> **Data unloading only**
>
> Definition
>
> **Specifies the extension for files unloaded to a stage.** Accepts any extension. The user is responsible for specifying a file extension that can be read by any desired software or services.

---

The table definition could use `FORMAT_TYPE` instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE CLUSTERS_SNOMED_ECL
(
    Code TEXT AS (value:"code"::TEXT)
    ,Display TEXT AS (value:"display"::TEXT)
    ,Version TEXT AS (value:"version"::TEXT)
    ,Cluster_Name TEXT AS (value:"cluster_name"::TEXT)
)
WITH LOCATION = @AZURE_STAGE_ECL_RAW/clusters.json
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_TYPE = JSON);
```

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions however still I am unable to refresh the table